# Check of Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

This afternoon I solved a ODE with a Laplace transform. Now I want to check if the solution whether it is correct, but I cannot get to the solution.
The ODE is:
$$\ddot{x} +4x = f(t), x(t=0)=3, \dot{x}(t=0)=-1$$
As a solution I found:$$ {x(t) =3\cos(2t)-\frac 12\sin(2t)+  \frac 12\int_0^t f(\tau) \, \sin(2(t-\tau))d\tau}$$

The problem is: How do I check the last part (under the integral?

Comment: In general for a linear second order equation, the factor under the integral multiplying $f(\tau)$ will be $G(t-\tau)$ where $G$ solves the homogeneous equation with the boundary conditions $G(0)=0,G'(0)=1$. Thus you have the particular solution correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, given $\ddot{x}+4x=f$ with $\dot{x}(0)=-1$ and $x(0)=3$, we find that

$$\mathscr{L}\{\ddot{x}\}=s^2\mathscr{L}\{x\}-3s+1 \tag1$$

Hence, we have

$$\mathscr{L}\{x\}=\underbrace{\frac{3s}{(s^2+4)}}_{\text{Laplace Transform of}\,\,3\cos(2t)}-\underbrace{\frac{1}{(s^2+4)}}_{\text{Laplace Transform of}\,\,\frac12\sin(2t)} +\underbrace{\frac{\mathscr{L}\{f\}}{(s^2+4)}}_{\text{Laplace Transform of}\,\,f(t)*\frac12\sin(2t)}$$

Inverting, we have

$$\begin{align}
x(t)&=3\cos(2t)-\frac12 \sin(2t) +\left(f(t)*\frac12\sin(2t)\right)\\\\
&=3\cos(2t)-\frac12 \sin(2t) +\frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau)u(\tau)\sin(2(t-\tau))u(t-\tau)\,d\tau\\\\
&=3\cos(2t)-\frac12 \sin(2t) +\frac12 \int_{0}^t f(\tau)\sin(2(t-\tau))\,d\tau\tag2
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

---

---

> We now verify that $(2)$ is the solution to the ODE of interest.

Differentiating $(2)$ using [Leibniz's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign), we find that

$$\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t)&=-2(3\sin(2t))+2\left(-\frac12 \cos(2t)\right)+\frac12 f(t)\sin(2(t-t))+\frac12 \int_0^t f(\tau) 2\cos(2(t-\tau))\,d\tau\\\\
&=-2(3\sin(2t))+2\left(-\frac12 \cos(2t)\right)+ \int_0^t f(\tau) \cos(2(t-\tau))\,d\tau \tag3
\end{align}$$

Differentiating $(3)$ again using [Leibniz's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign), we find that

$$\begin{align}
\ddot{x}(t)&=-4(3\cos(2t))-4\left(-\frac12 \sin(2t)\right)+f(t)\cos(2(t-t))-4\,\frac12 \int_0^t f(\tau)\sin(2(t-\tau))\,d\tau\\\\
&=-4x(t)+f(t)
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: I still struggle with this Leibniz rule. To Be honest I don’t know What The idea is behind this rule. Are there Some easy examples?

Comment: Have you read the article in the link I provided?

Comment: @MarkViola: Yes I read the article, but I can't see what I am really doing. I try to understand the steps. But I have to find some real simple examples. The examples in the article are still complicated.

Comment: You know the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  So if the integrand was independent of $t$, then do you see that $\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^t f(\tau)\sin(x-\tau)\,d\tau=f(t)\sin(x-t)$?  And if the upper limit of integration was independent of $t$, then do you see that $\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^x f(\tau)\sin(t-\tau)\,d\tau=\int_0^x f(\tau)\cos(t-\tau)\,d\tau$?

Comment: Thanks Mark, that was the missing link! I think I got it now!

Comment: I am struggling now with the integral: $$\int_{0}^{t} \tau \sin2(t-\tau) d\tau$$. I have to deduce the value without direct integration. (so not using integration by parts)

Comment: Do you want the integral or its derivative?

Comment: it is possible to deduce the value of the integral, but not use direct integration! So there must be some kind of 'trick'. I know the value already, (used Int by parts.)

Comment: HINT:  Take the LT of the convolution integral.

Comment: Using your hint: the integral is a result of: $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(F(s)G(s)=\int_{0}^{t} \tau \sin2(t-\tau) d\tau$, so thinking back gives: $F(s)=\sin (2s)$ and $G(s)= s$. Thinking back in LT: $\mathcal{L}(\sin(2s) = \frac{2}{a^2 +4}$ and $\mathcal{L} s = \frac{1}{s^2}$. But now?